# Individual class accuracy calculation confusion

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification

The total number of data points for which the following binary classification result is obtained = 1500. Out of which, I have

- 1473 labelled as `0` and
- the remaining 27 as `1` .

As can be seen from the confusion matrix, out of 27 data points belonging to class `1`, I got only 1 data point misclassified as `0`  . So, I calculated the accuracy for individual classes and got  Accuracy for class labelled as 0 = 98.2% and for the other as 1.7333%. Is this calculation correct? I am not sure...I did get a pretty good classification for the class labelled as `1` so why the accuracy for it is low?
The individual class accuracies should have been 100% for class0 and around 98% for class1

Does one misclassification reduce the accuracy of class 1 by so much amount? This is the how I calculated the individual class accuracies in MAtlab.

```
cmMatrix  = 
1473    0
1       26

acc_class0  = 100*(cmMatrix(1,1))/1500;
acc_class1= 100*(cmMatrix(2,2))/1500;
```

Comment: Your computation is not correct. [This section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_(classification_context)) has a good overview of the various error measures and how to compute them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If everything had been classified correctly, your computation would indicate accuracy for class 1 as 27/1500=0.018. This is obviously wrong. Overall accuracy is 1499/1500, but per-class accuracy cannot use 1500 as denominator. 27 is the maximum correctly classified elements, and should therefore be the denominator.

```
acc_class0 = 100*cmMatrix(1,1)/sum(cmMatrix(1,:));
acc_class1 = 100*cmMatrix(2,2)/sum(cmMatrix(2,:));
```